# MPI program doesn't start right away (Fedora)

Tags: fedora, mpi

sorry I'm not sure if this is better asked here or Stack Overflow, but this is with a fresh Fedora 39 install, and I've tested it with the packages (installed via dnf) mpich-devel, openmpi-devel and (from linux-homebrew) openmpi and I get the same problem. I guess this has to do with the system, which is why I thought it's better asked here.

Basically, if I try to run an MPI program that contains MPI_Init, it does run, but it takes a very long time to actually start. It also doesn't show up in `top` immediately; it seems it gets delayed for some reason. When it does appear, it runs as quickly as I would expect. Here's a simple hello world MPI program in Fortran:

```
program hello_world
    use mpi
    implicit none
    integer :: mpi_size, mpi_rank
    integer :: ierr
    double precision :: t1, t2

    call MPI_Init(ierr)
    t1 = MPI_Wtime()

    call MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, mpi_size, ierr)
    call MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, mpi_rank, ierr)

    print*, "Hello from rank ", mpi_rank, " of ", mpi_size, "."

    t2 = MPI_Wtime()
    print*, "time for full program", t2-t1
    call MPI_Finalize(ierr)

end program hello_world
```

I can compile this with mpif90 (no errors) and I can run it with a delay of maybe a few minutes. I looked up what might be causing it and on similar posts it was suggested to close other programs and to disable wifi (don't know why?), but none of that helped.

Here is the output for `time mpirun -np 2 ./a.out`

```
 Hello from rank            0  of            2 .
 time for full program   1.3940195000000001E-002
 Hello from rank            1  of            2 .
 time for full program   1.4017349000000000E-002

real    2m27.524s
user    0m0.033s
sys 0m0.163s
```

For comparison, here's a much simpler hello world program,

```
program hello
    print *, 'Hello, World!'
end program hello
```

If I compile with `mpif90`, and time it (ran with one processor here to compare against gfortran), I get:

```
 Hello, World!

real    1m13.201s
user    0m0.016s
sys 0m0.074s
```

With gfortran, (doesn't matter if I run with `./a.out` or `mpirun -np 1 ./a.out`)

```
 Hello, World!

real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.001s
```

It looks like it also intermittently works with no wait. (enough so that I deleted this question thinking an update fixed it, but when I ran it again the problem was back)

Edit: Looks like the problem is in `MPI_Init` somehow. You can put in calls like

```
    call date_and_time(values=values)
    print *, values(5),":",values(6),":",values(7),":",values(8)
```

to find the time at certain lines, and the bottleneck is `MPI_Init`.

Example:
Program start time:

`17 :          20 :           6 :         221`

After `MPI_Init`:

`17 :          21 :          21 :         128`

After `MPI_Finalize`:

`17 :          21 :          21 :         132`